# Element doesn't add a class until certain code has executed, but I want it to do it before

Tags: javascript, css, asynchronous, promise, es6-promise

I made a simple program in js that changes the aspect ratio of user uploaded images,I know that this is probably not the best way to do this sort of thing, but I think of it as practice.[Here's the repo](https://github.com/kxrn0/Resize-Images), and [here's a live version](https://kxrn0.github.io/Resize-Images/).

There's a div with class `.loading-screen` that is supposed to cover the entire screen while the images are being processed, that div is initially hidden with a simple class that has a
property of `display : none;`.

Once the user presses the "process" button for resizing the images, I try to remove the `.hidden` class from `.loading-screen`, but it doesn't remove it, it goes straight into processing the images, and once it's done it actually removes the class, but once the images have been finished processing, I add the class back again, so it's added and then removed immediately after. The basic flow relevant parts of the program is as follows :

```
const input = document.querySelector(".file-input");
const processButton = document.querySelector(".process");
let imageDivs = [];

input.addEventListener("change", () => {
  //load the images into the program, and store 
  //the resulting divs with images inside of the
  //imageDivs array
});

processButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const loadingScreen = document.querySelector(".loading-screen"); //this is the div that I want to cover the screen with

  loadingScreen.classList.remove("hidden"); //remove the '.hidden' class, so that it will cover the entire window

  let promises = [];
  
  for (let div of imageDivs) {
    let img = div.querySelector("img");

    //fit_image() draws the image in a canvas, and then 
    //returns a promise that resolves to the base64 data
    //of the canvas
    promises.push(fit_image(img));
  }

  Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
    loadingScreen.classList.add("hidden"); //hide this div once we are done processing the images

    //load the resized images into the program, etc...
  });
});
```

The problem is that `loadingScreen.classList.remove("hidden")` seems to run after the images have finished being processed, because if I remove the `loadingScreen.classList.add("hidden")` inside of the `Promises.all()` statement, the `loadingScreen` div appears after the images are done. How do I make it load the class before the images start processing?

Comment: Without knowing exactly what fit_image does it's diffiult to be certain of the problem, but have you tried forcing a repaint when unsetting hidden? Using requestAnimationFrame should help, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37953871/how-to-force-repaint-in-js otherwise the browser may not be redrawing the screen but just finishing everything and then hidden gets set again.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. the code for the fit_image() function is on https://github.com/kxrn0/Resize-Images/blob/main/src/fitness.js